# Getting error from kubenetes server while logging in - ClusterRoleBinding

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, rbac

I am using Keycloak as my identity provider for kubernetes. I am using kubelogin to get the token. The token seems to work but I am getting the below error. I think there is some issue in the ClusterRoleBinding which is not allowing it to work.

- Whats the error

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "test" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default"
```

**Additional Information**

- Api Manifest

```
    - --oidc-issuer-url=https://test1.example.com/auth/realms/kubernetes
    - --oidc-username-claim=preferred_username
    - --oidc-username-prefix=-
    - --oidc-groups-claim=groups
    - --oidc-client-id=kubernetes
    - --oidc-ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/ca.crt
```

- Cluster role and cluster role binding

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: admin-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: //test1.example.com.com/auth/realms/kubernetes#23fd6g03-e03e-450e-8b5d-07b19007c443
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Is there anything I am missing to get this to work?

Comment: I am analyzing your issue. In a meantime could you please add `apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io` to your `subjects:` User definition? Seems like it is missing.
And also please share your `ClusterRole` definitions configs within your question.

Comment: @OhHiMark Yes I have edited the question with cluster role. Also I have added the `apiGroup` in the subjects. Can you please check and let me know whats the issue with this.

Comment: And you still got the same issue after adding the `apiGroup` as I suggested?

Comment: @OhHiMark Rather than adding the url, I have to add the user name in the cluster role. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging a lot I could find the issue. Rather than adding the keycloak url for the user, we have to use the user name itself. Here is the example yaml

```yaml
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cluster-admin
rules:
- apiGroups: ["*"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: admin-rolebinding
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: test
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```